# How to use global variables inside the setup Vuetify 3

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api, vuetifyjs3

Im using the vue 3 setup and I want to access global variable vuetify that I use.
I can see it in the config.globalVariable but I cant use it in setup.

```js
{_uid: 0, _component: {…}, _props: null, _container: div#app, _context: {…}, …}
component: ƒ component(name, component)
config: Object
compilerOptions: (...)
errorHandler: undefined
globalProperties:
$vuetify: {defaults: {…}}
$messageSystem: {addMessage: ƒ}
__proto__: Object
isNativeTag: (tag) => {…}
...
```

as you can see I see the $vuetify, but on the setup I cant access it.

```js
    setup() {
       ...
       this.$vuetify.theme.dark = true; 
       ...
```

Is this how I access a global variable?

The Error I get:
`Cannot read property '$vuetify' of undefined`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot get access to `this` inside the `setup` hook but you can use `getCurrentInstance` to get the app instance which contains the config :

```
import { getCurrentInstance,onMounted } from 'vue'

export default {
  setup() {
    const internalInstance = getCurrentInstance()

    onMounted(()=>{
      nternalInstance.appContext.config.globalProperties.$vuetify.theme.dark=true
   })
  }
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed, thank you!
Edit: it gives me null when I try to log `internalInstace` in setup right after I do `const internalInstance = getCurrentInstance` not inside a method for some reason, I'll do the research, but any idea why it gives null?

Comment: try it out inside `onMounted` hook like `onMounted(()=>{console.log(internalInstance)})`